# Any way to include a batch of Library and Directory paths to "Include Additional Directories" Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, batch-file, visual-c++, environment-variables

Currently, when working on a new solution in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 (C++), my team has to include a bunch of libraries and directories individually. Which is tedious and prone to mistakes. Is there anyway to be able to include one path(Environment Variable) in "Additional Include Directories" that contains all the paths to the "Includes" we need without individually including each and every path or any other solution? Right now, when we create a new solution we have to repeatedly add every solution individually.

Comment: Please note the [tag:batch-file] tag does not meaning processing many files. You can hover onto a tag to see its actual meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to view->Other windows->Property manager and then open one of the project nodes and then one node for each of the platforms of interest (that is Debug|Win32, Debug|X64), and right click on the Microsoft.Cpp..User node and select properties.

Now, you can edit this property page just like a project properties but the settings will be applied to all projects (even already created projects).